# How to get the host name of a system on the LAN using IP in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the machine name with specific LAN IP address.

The code I tried so far :

```
InetAddress addresss = InetAddress.GetByName("192.168.1.101");
bool test = addresss.IsReachable(500);
string name = addresss.CanonicalHostName;
string name0 = addresss.HostName;
```

But it always return the same IP that I have entered.

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether are you able to ping that system with this ip **192.168.1.101** from terminal or cmd :

Type `ping 192.168.1.101` and press <kbd>return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then try this code :

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.101");
        System.out.println("Machine Name : " + address.getHostName());
    }

}
```

Note : The system with ip - **192.168.1.101** should exist, otherwise you will get error.